# Kendo Grid Filter on a dynamic column

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on a Kendo Grid which has a Status column that is an aggregate of statuses of several other columns. I track the individual statuses as integer values and the aggregate column should show the least of the statuses. Now, using template, I am able to render the text for the Status column fine, however, the problem is that I want this column to be filterable. This is not working as the value is calculated.

In DataSource, this is how I have declared the custom field,

```
schema: {
    model: {
        Status: function () {
            return helper.GetStatus(this.EntriesStatus);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I used it in the Column definition,

```
{
    field: "Status",
    title: "Status",
    width: "100px",
    filterable: true,
    template: kendo.template("#if (HasError) {# <strong class='clrRed' > \#= Status() #\ </strong> #} else { # \#= Status() #\ #} #"),
    hidden: false,
    menu: false
}
```

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong or a more efficient way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining `Status` as a function in the `model`, add it in `model.parse` as a computed field. Ex:

```
schema: {
    parse: function (d) {
        $.each(d, function (idx, elem) {
            elem.Status = helper.GetStatus(elem.EntriesStatus);
        });
        return d;
    }
}
```

And then in the template remove `()`:

```
template: kendo.template("#if (HasError) {# <strong class='clrRed' > \#= Status #\ </strong> #} else { # \#= Status #\ #} #"),
```