# kendo grid column filtering when bind to the Id field

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Please find the DOJO: [DOJO](http://dojo.telerik.com/ozADeT/4)

I have a custom dropdown editor for user field. Editors and templates everything is working fine. But when I want to filter the User column using the names, it is not working. It is because I am binding the userId in the field option. So kendo grid is searching for only UserId field, not UserName in the data source.

Whenever I save the grid only the UserId field will get saved to the database. So I should bind the UserId field to the column.

My requirement is to search using the Name in the User Column, not the UserId.

Please let me know what will be the approach.

Comment: This seems related --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520479/kendo-grid-filter-on-a-dynamic-column

Answer (score 0):

In the code for your grid you need to change field from `UserId` to `UserName` like below:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    filterable: true,
    columns: [
        {field: "UserName", title: "User", width: "180px", editor: userDropDownEditor, template: userTemplate},
        {field:"role"}
    ],
    editable: true
});
```

The filter will then look at UserName instead of the id. Here's is the updated [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ozADeT/7).